# Running a simple ruby file in docker and redirecting the output to a file

Tags: ruby, docker

Say I have a ruby file in my current directory hello.rb:

puts "hello world"

How can I run a docker image that will simply run this ruby file and then save the output to a file.

What is the smallest footprint docker image I can use for this?

I tried this docker image:
https://github.com/iron-io/dockers/tree/master/ruby

But i'm not sure how to run it correctly to do what I want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a new directory, move your `hello.rb` file there, and create this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ruby:latest
COPY hello.rb .
ENTRYPOINT ["ruby", "hello.rb"]
```

That grabs the latest docker image with Ruby installed, copies your `hello.rb` file into the container, then specifies an executable entry point as if you ran `ruby hello.rb` in a shell.

Next, run `docker build -t rubytest .`. This will pull down the `ruby:latest` image from Docker Hub then execute the commands in the `Dockerfile`. Note that `rubytest` in this command can be substituted with anything you wanted to tag your container with.

Finally, run `docker run -t rubytest . > output.txt`. This will run your `hello.rb` executable, redirecting the output to `output.txt` in your current directory.

Comment: I get: Unable to find image 'rubytest:latest' locally docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for rubytest, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.

Comment: @Blankman what is the exact `docker run` command you are using?

Comment: exactly what you wrote ```docker run -t rubytest . > output.txt```

Comment: I neglected to mention the need to run `docker build -t rubytest .` first in my answer. I've edited it.